# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: with os.path.dirname and os.path.join in windows using python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I would like to read a file using the following code:

```
import os

DIRNAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)
mydir=os.path.join(DIRNAME,'test.json')
myfile = open(mydir)  # alice.txt is in the same dir as foo.py
mytxt = myfile.read()
myfile.close()
```

I have the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/user/Documents/MyTest\\test.json'
```

I have the `test.json` in that directory but I am not sure why I have that error. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is mixing forward and backslashes. You can solve by replacing forward slashes in `DIRNAME`:

```
DIRNAME = '\\'.join(os.path.dirname(__file__).split("/"))
mydir=os.path.join(DIRNAME,'test.json')
print mydir
```

Returns:

```
C:\Users\f3k\Documents\temp\test.json
```